# Dict comprehension failing - Python 3.6.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am trying to write a `dict` comprehension that creates a `dict` where the `k,v` pair is `column_title, # of null values in that column` for my `pandas df`.

I have the following:
`df1_null_dict = {c:df1.c.isnull().sum() for c in df1}`

Which follows [this example](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-dictionary-comprehension) of how to build dict comprehensions in Python.

However, I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-a4c7d72985f6> in <module>
----> 1 df1_null_dict = {c:df1.c.isnull().sum() for c in df1}
      2 df2_null_dict = {c:df2.c.isnull().sum() for c in df2}

<ipython-input-5-a4c7d72985f6> in <dictcomp>(.0)
----> 1 df1_null_dict = {c:df1.c.isnull().sum() for c in df1}
      2 df2_null_dict = {c:df2.c.isnull().sum() for c in df2}

c:\python367-64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5137             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5138                 return self[name]
-> 5139             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5140 
   5141     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'c'
```

How can I use dict comprehension to achieve my desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use alternative for select by `[]` working well with variables:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
         'C':[np.nan,8,9,4,np.nan,np.nan],
         'D':[1,3,5,np.nan,1,0],
         'E':[np.nan,3,6,9,2,np.nan],

})

df1_null_dict = {c:df1[c].isnull().sum() for c in df1}
print (df1_null_dict)
{'C': 3, 'D': 1, 'E': 2}
```

Alternative is create `Series` and convert to dictionary:

```
df1_null_dict = df1.isnull().sum().to_dict()
print (df1_null_dict)
{'C': 3, 'D': 1, 'E': 2}
```